# Reference Error at window.location.change(url)

Tags: javascript

I was trying to create a basic login form, but after successful login, I could not get my page to redirect to another URL. Instead, it was loading the redirected page on the same URL.

```
app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const email = req.body.email;
        const password = req.body.password;

        const userEmail = await Users.findOne({email:email});
        
        if(userEmail.password === password) {
            // res.render("index.hbs");
            res.send("Wait for it");
            setTimeout(function() {
                window.open("localhost:port/home");
                console.log("This is new url");
            }, 500);
        } else {
            res.send("Invalid login details");
            
        }
    } catch {
        res.send("Invalid login details").status(400);
    }
})
```

Comment: `window` is on the client. This is node.js code that runs on the server.

Comment: Where is `window.location.change()` in the posted code?

Answer (score 0):

Use the useNavigate to fixed your problem
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"

```
    const AnalyticTracker = (props) => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    return (
            <form onSubmit={() => navigate('../', { replace: true })}>
            {...}
            </form>
               )
```

)